# Deleted comments are still displaying in the stackexchange.com "activity" -> "comments" section

Tags: bug, comments, stackexchange.com, network-profile, activity

When I'm seeing my comments from the individual site's ["activity" -> "comments"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/312043/arulkumar?tab=activity&sort=comments) section the deleted comments are not displaying, but when I'm seeing the comments from the network wide in the stackexchange.com ["activity" -> "comments"](https://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar?tab=activity&sort=comments) section, the deleted comments are still displaying in that.

So the deleted comments can be removed from the network wide comment sections too?

**Screenshot from Meta Stack Exchange:**

> [image: MSE]

**Screenshot from Stack Exchange:**

> [image: SE.com]